# How to get length of the buffer which is just received from socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, buffer, posix

I am using the `#include <sys/socket.h>` library socket connection with server and using `vector` of type `char` for receiving the data from the socket connection which as shown below:

```
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int sock, valread;
    sock = 0;

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "0.0.0.0", &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
    }
    std::vector<char> buffer = {0};
    buffer.reserve(1024);
    read(sock, buffer.data(), 1024);
```

Since the server response size is variable in length but not more than `1024` so that why the size of `buffer` fixed to `1024`.
Now since I am receiving variable size response I want to know the size of the `buffer`.
I tried following:

```
std::cout<<sizeof(buffer)<<" "<<buffer.size();
```

and output is

```
 sizeof(buffer) = 32
 buffer.size() = 1
```

if I try `1024` value that comes up with the some garbage values which is as follow:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
{
    std::cout<<buffer[i];
}
```

output:

[{"xmin": 95, "ymin": 147, "ymax": 276, "xmax": 193}, {"xmin": 42, "ymin": 353, "ymax": 488, "xmax": 123}, {"xmin": 85, "ymin": 19, "ymax": 166, "xmax": 145}, {"xmin": 1, "ymin": 254, "ymax": 327, "xmax": 107}, {"xmin": 393, "ymin": 281, "ymax": 419, "xmax": 463}, {"xmin": 379, "ymin": 316, "ymax": 457, "xmax": 442}]������� ��!� )��0� 8��?� G��N� V��]� e��l� t��{� ����� ����� ����� ����� ���Ʈ ή�ծ ݮ��� ����� ����

So is there any way we can get exact size of response?

Comment: Use the return-value of `read`. Your programs should _always_ inspect every function-call's return value because that's the idiom in C to indicate error conditions, for example.

Comment: `buffer.reserve(1024);` this only reserves but not set vector size.

Comment: @Dai not quite :) It is the idiom of that library. In C++ there is also exceptions. So more general, read the documentation of any library and don't skip over the details they are always important.

Comment: @PepijnKramer `read` is a C function in POSIX, not a C++ function. The idiom to check function return-values is [an _ecosystem-wide_ C idiom](https://riptutorial.com/c/example/15692/ignoring-return-values-of-library-functions), not just one of any specific library.

Comment: Ok I see now. Question was marked C++. Should have been "C" then

Comment: @PepijnKramer No, the C++ tag is still appropriate (as the OP is using `vector<char>`), it's just that they're using the BSD Sockets and POSIX API, both of which are C APIs, but from within C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Always inspect return-values in C-style APIs!**

C-style APIs are directly callable from most other programming languages, including C++. Because portable C doesn't support thrown exceptions C-style library APIs are designed indicate error conditions typically through return-values (e.g. returning `NULL` or a negative value) while *output data* (e.g. byte buffers, struct pointers, etc) is passed through pointers passed as parameters. Because C exposes raw program memory it means that you can easily crash your process ([or worse...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow)) if you attempt to use an invalid pointer or if the library you're using indicates it's in an invalid-state or terminal-state (e.g. `eof` on file streams).

---

POSIX's `read` function returns the number of bytes actually written into the buffer.

> https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html
>
> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates
> end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number.
>
> It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of
> bytes requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes
> are actually available right now (maybe because we were close to
> end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a
> terminal), or because `read()` was interrupted by a signal.

Note this part:

> this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available right now

...which means you need to call `read` in a loop until it returns zero.

Like so:

```c
using std::vector<char>; // Consider using `std::Array` instead as it's a fixed-size buffer.

//

const size_t bufferLength = 1024;

vector<char> buffer(/*n:*/ bufferLength);

char* bufferPtr = buffer.data();
size_t totalRead = 0;
while( totalRead < bufferLength )
{
    char* bufferPtrOffset = bufferPtr + totalRead;

    ssize_t bytesRead = read( /*fd:*/ sock, /*buffer:*/ bufferPtrOffset, /*count:*/ bufferLength - totalRead );
    if( bytesRead < 0 )
    {
        // TODO: Error condition. Throw an exception or something.
    }
    else if( bytesRead == 0 )
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        totalRead += bytesRead;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [@Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai). I should use the return value of the function `read`
Thanks again.

Comment: You also need to call `read` in a loop _until_ it reads zero btw.

Comment: That or loop until it provides all of the bytes you were expecting. When you read from a stream socket, you get what's available in the stream up to the number of bytes requested. If you need 10000 bytes, you may have to keep asking for more data until all 10000 arrive. Never assume you got the whole message because streams don't know what you consider a message and frankly they don't care.

Comment: Deep down they do care; they just never learned how to express their feelings.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm surprised that BSD Sockets didn't come with helper functions for correctly and safely-handling fixed-size and delimited messages. That alone would have saved us from countless buffer-overrun vulnerabilities over the decades.

Comment: Agreed. I can see the, "We can't cover everyone's use cases!" but I think you can cover 90-95%, and the people writing code that needs those outlier cases should be capable of rolling their own.

Comment: @Dai: they come with stdio -- you can use `fdopen(socket, "r+")` and then use fread/fwrite for fixed-size data or fgets for newline-delimited text.  Or fscanf for other delimiters, though dealing with NULs can be tricky.  For some uses it might be better to fdopen two FILE for a socket (one "r" and ont "w"), but that works too, if done carefully.